# Idempiere installasion with eclipse- maven

Tags: maven, idempiere

I installed idempiere using eclipse and maven,
I use :

- eclipse 2023-03
- maven 3.6.3
- java 11

menemukan error :
error(44 item)

- Conflicting lifecycle mapping metadata (project packaging type="eclipse-feature"): Mapping defined in 'org.eclipse.m2e.pde.connector_2.1.2.20221218-1726 [613]' and 'org.sonatype.tycho.m2e_0.10.0.20220926-1324 [960]'. To enable full functionality, remove the conflicting mapping and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.    pom.xml /org.adempiere.base.feature line 11 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
- Conflicting lifecycle mapping metadata (project packaging type="eclipse-feature"): Mapping defined in 'org.eclipse.m2e.pde.connector_2.1.2.20221218-1726 [613]' and 'org.sonatype.tycho.m2e_0.10.0.20220926-1324 [960]'. To enable full functionality, remove the conflicting mapping and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.    pom.xml /org.adempiere.payment.processor.feature    line 11 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ee3k.png)

I have used several methods such as deleting files/folders
m2e.pde.connector and org.sonatype.tycho.m2e